# java App Transport Security error on m1 Macbook

Tags: java, apple-m1, app-transport-security

I have just started learning java 2 months ago and basically I am taking baby step in learning how to programing. And even worse, I am completely new to macOS. So one code line -> one google search, taking a lot of time. My life was all along with Window.

This time I was trying to do study JSP / Spring. During process, I got message like this -

**http://localhost:8081/Hello/index.jsp
Page load failed with error: The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.**

(* I changed the port 8080 to 8081 because I got error saying port 8080 is already occupied even though I do not use it anywhere. I even killed entire process on terminal
`kill -9 pid`. And I was still getting same error msg)

I am currently using M1 macbook air. I have tried some several things after I searched on google.

To note, I installed Apache Tomcat 9.0 and located them in -

```
/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.50
```

and gave them sudo chmod using terminal.

And I downloaded java as -

```
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

Firstly, I downloaded openJDK16 using Homebrew command. I deleted it and installed jdk 1.8 on oracle official website, which I think irrelevant.

Couple of things I have tried -

1. reinstalled entire os (BigSur)
2. changed Info.plist on java local directory. Modified it with App Transport Security - Allow something something to YES as a root user
3. Tried to synchronize Tomcat on VS code.
4. Tried to synchronize Tomcat on STS4 Maven project
5. remove java program and related files and reinstall
6. any related articles with this issue on google

Still I am not sure how to solve this App Trasport Security issue on my m1 macbook.

There is Info.plist on -

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents
```

Is this a keyfile to disable ATS?
I've tried to modify it using root user because it denied any action and I ended up re-install it. After I added a new line about ATS, I could not even open the eclipse or sts4 app. It gave me an error msg saying I am not authorized to open this app.

[java Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWrf2.png)

[java Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1FJa.png)

Comment: Have you found a solution yet mate ?

Answer (score -1):

**It seems to be an IOS security policy.
I recommend that you try the second method from the url below.**

url : *https://littleshark.tistory.com/1*

Comment: Please don't post link  only answers. If link becomes dead, this answer becomes invalid. Rather post the answer by keeping link's content as a base.